# Binding combobox and JLabel array, pictures together

Tags: java, swing, oop, jlabel, jcombobox

I need some help here for a GUI with Java OOP, I am using Eclipse.

I am creating a "select airlines" GUI with Combobox, JLabel and pictures.

1st choice,  F16(combobox) add $600(JLabel) F16.jpg (outside of the combobox).

But inside the panel while selected the 2nd choice F22(combobox) the JLabel should automatically change add $900(JLabel) as well as the picture to F12.jpg

any guys can help me with Combobox,the JLabel coding, pictures

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you add some code to your question, it will be easier for people to help you. Don't post all of your code, just an [SSCCE](http://www.mindprod.com/jgloss/sscce.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you want to use an `ItemListener` on your `JComboBox`:

```
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
        // Adds a listener - this performs an action when the item changes.
        box.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                //Checks if this event was caused because an item was selected
                if((e.getStateChange() & ItemEvent.SELECTED) == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    System.out.println(e.getItem());
                    // This is where you'd modify your label based on the dropdown's value - something like this:
                    label.setText("$900");
                }
            }});
        panel.add(box);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to adjust more of the codes, because basically, when i selected back to the f16 (combobox) first choice, the add value still remains as $900, is there modified code to change back to the original value $600?

Comment: ok i have figure out the code, now i able to shuffle the jlabel and combobox, but now left is the picture together. any help ? thanks!

Comment: If you have 3 items that are linked together, I'd recommend making a class out of them (look here for some instructions): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html .  Better yet, you can override the `toString()` function in that class, then use it as your objects in your `JComboBox`.  When the item changes, you can get your updated info directly from the `e.getItem()` function.